# How to disable a button depending on the length of a list

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic4

I want that the user can choose only one tag. So the button should be disabled after the user has pushed one tag to the list. So I made up the idea that if the list.length is bigger than 0, the button should be disabled. But somehow it doesn't work in my approach.

page.html

```
 <ion-item>
      <ion-input mode="md" formControlName="category" clearInput="true" placeholder="Tag" name="tagValue"></ion-input>
      <ion-button [disabled]="!categoryForm.valid" [disabled]="tagList?.length > 1"  item-right type="submit" icon-only>
      <ion-icon name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
    </ion-item>
```

page.ts

```
  public tagInput: string = '';
  public tagList: any[] = [];

constructor() {}
...
addTag() { // properly access and reset reactive form values
  const tagCtrl = this.categoryForm.get('category');
  if (tagCtrl.value) {
    this.tagList.push(tagCtrl.value);
    this.tagInput = ''; // in order to have an empty input
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using disable attribute twice:

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-input mode="md" formControlName="category" clearInput="true" placeholder="Tag" name="tagValue"></ion-input>
      <ion-button [disabled]="!categoryForm.valid || tagList?.length > 0"  item-right type="submit" icon-only>
      <ion-icon name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
    </ion-item>
```

Comment: I guess it should be a `||` instead of `&&`, and length should be >0 instead of 1... if OP confirms...

Comment: That's true. I agree :)